# Thymeleaf - th:each into JSON-LD

Tags: thymeleaf, json-ld

I'm hoping to loop through an array of Thymeleaf variables to generate JSON-LD (with Schema.org), similar to [Google's examples for store departments](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/local-businesses/#a_store_with_multiple_departments).

I know you can loop through an array in Thymeleaf in HTML like this:

```
<tr th:each="prod : ${prods}">
  <td th:text="${prod.name}">Onions</td>
  <td th:text="${prod.price}">2.41</td>
  <td th:text="${prod.inStock}? #{true} : #{false}">yes</td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to do the same into a JSON-LD format?

Answer (score 0):

I am affraid it is not possible to be achieved on client. You need to prepare JSON on server and send it as a string to client.

So prepare you entity for JSON, like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class FaqAnswerLdJson extends AbstractLdJson implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("price")
    private String price;

    ...
}
```

Then serialize it to JSON on server and put to a model.

On client you can render it like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" th:utext="${json}">
</script>
```